# Is there any plan to merge `qt-components-ubuntu` into official QT/QML?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, qt5

Is there any plan to merge `qt-components-ubuntu` into official QT/QML? Is it ongoing already? It's quite sad that ubuntu forked `qt`. I want to use `qml` to build a desktop app, and widgets introduced in `qt-components-ubuntu` are what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu developers didn't fork Qt. They just added a custom library for native Ubuntu apps. [Digia](http://qt.digia.com/) is the owner of Qt, so only they can include Ubuntu components into default Qt libs, but its probablity is very low because core feature of Qt is cross-platform support.

Comment: Why should qt-components-ubuntu be not cross-platform? I thought it was written in qml. Even if it is a c++ and qt code, it still should be portable.